# Creating Sudoku in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a sudoku who generate by js function, i try to show it with react but i dont know why this doent work.

I try to create 81 squares who have inside a input with a id and value, value, when i put a number inside it will execute function comprobar and put its background on read or white if its correct.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import "./index.css";

    /*Se genera el diseño */
    var fallo;

    // Array que contendra las posiciones que se mostrarán
    var array = new Array(9);

    // Array de 9x9 que contiene la solucion. generada
    for (var z = 0; z < 9; z++) {
      array[z] = new Array(9);
    }

    function rellenarCuad(n, m) {
      // Método que recibe el punto de comienzo del cuadrado
      var x = n * 3;
      var z = m * 3;
      var arrN = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

      /* En este método se procede a rellenar el cuadrado 3x3 cumpliendo que no se repita en el mismo, en la fila y en la columna */
      for (var i = x; i < 3 + x; i++) {
        for (var j = z; j < 3 + z; j++) {
          var arrayaux = new Array(9);

          for (var zn = 0; zn < 9; zn++) arrayaux[zn] = array[zn][j];

          var pr = true;
          var intentos = 0;

          do {
            do {
              var nm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9, 0);
            } while (arrN[nm] == 0);

            if (
              array[i].indexOf(arrN[nm]) === -1 &&
              arrayaux.indexOf(arrN[nm]) === -1
            ) {
              array[i][j] = arrN[nm];
              arrN[nm] = 0;
              pr = false;
            }

            if (intentos > 50) {
              // Si rebasa 50 intentos doy por hecho que no tiene solucion

              fallo = true;
              return;
            }

            intentos++;
          } while (pr);
        }
      }
    }

    // Método que genera el sodoku. Es recursivo, si no se halla una solución se llama a si mismo hasta encontrarla
    function generarSodoku() {
      // Método que simplemente llamar a rellenarCuad por cada cuadrado 3x3, es decir, le llama 9 veces
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
          rellenarCuad(y, i);
          if (fallo) {
            //  Si el seguro se activa, regenera el array y se llama asi mismo para repetir el proceso.

            fallo = false;
            array = null;
            array = new Array(9);

            for (z = 0; z < 9; z++) array[z] = new Array(9);

            generarSodoku();
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Función que genera el numero de posiciones a ocultar según la eleción del usuario
    function umbral() {
      var nm = 80;
      var arrayM = new Array(nm);

      for (var l = 0; l < nm; l++) {
        var alpha = true;
        while (alpha) {
          var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 81) + 1;
          if (arrayM.indexOf(num) !== -1) {
          } else {
            arrayM[l] = num;
            alpha = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    generarSodoku();

    console.log(array);

    var valoresVacios = [0];

    function generarAleatorios() {
        for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            do {
                var numAlea = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80);

            } while (!valoresVacios.indexOf(valoresVacios[i]));
            valoresVacios[i] = numAlea;
        }
    }

    generarAleatorios();

    function comprobar(value, i) {
      if (valoresVacios.indexOf(i)) {
        var valor = Math.floor(i / 9);
        var segundo = (i / 9).toFixed(1);
        segundo = (segundo - valor) * 10;
        if (array[valor][segundo] !== value) {
          document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else {
          document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
      }
    } 


    function Square(props) {
        return (
          <input className="square" type="text" onkeypress={comprobar(this.value, this.id)} />
        );
      }

      class Board extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            squares: Array(81),
          };
        }

        comprobar(value, i) {
            if (valoresVacios.indexOf(i)) {
              var valor = Math.floor(i / 9);
              var segundo = (i / 9).toFixed(1);
              segundo = (segundo - valor) * 10;
              if (array[valor][segundo] !== value) {
                document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
              } else {
                document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor = "white";
              }
            }
          } 

        renderSquare(a, i) {
            if (valoresVacios.indexOf(i)) {
              return <Square value={0} id={i} onkeypress={() => this.comprobar(a, i)}/>;
            } else {
              return <Square value={a} id={i} disabled onkeypress={() => this.comprobar(a, i)}/>;
            }
          }

        render() {
          /*const winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
          let status;
          if (winner) {
            status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
          }*/

          return (
            <div>
                <div className="status">{}</div>
                <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(array[0][0], 0)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[0][1], 1)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[0][2], 2)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[0][3], 3)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[0][4], 4)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[0][5], 5)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[0][6], 6)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[0][7], 7)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[0][8], 8)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(array[1][0], 9)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[1][1], 10)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[1][2], 11)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[1][3], 12)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[1][4], 13)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[1][5], 14)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[1][6], 15)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[1][7], 16)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[1][8], 17)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(array[2][0], 18)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[2][1], 19)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[2][2], 20)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[2][3], 21)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[2][4], 22)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[2][5], 23)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[2][6], 24)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[2][7], 25)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[2][8], 26)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(array[3][0], 27)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[3][1], 28)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[3][2], 29)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[3][3], 30)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[3][4], 31)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[3][5], 32)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[3][6], 33)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[3][7], 34)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[3][8], 35)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(array[4][0], 36)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[4][1], 37)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[4][2], 38)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[4][3], 39)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[4][4], 40)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[4][5], 41)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[4][6], 42)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[4][7], 43)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[4][8], 44)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(array[5][0], 45)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[5][1], 46)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[5][2], 47)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[5][3], 48)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[5][4], 49)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[5][5], 50)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[5][6], 51)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[5][7], 52)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[5][8], 53)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(array[6][0], 54)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[6][1], 55)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[6][2], 56)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[6][3], 57)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[6][4], 58)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[6][5], 59)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[6][6], 60)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[6][7], 61)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[6][8], 62)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(array[7][0], 63)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[7][1], 64)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[7][2], 65)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[7][3], 66)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[7][4], 67)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[7][5], 68)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[7][6], 69)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[7][7], 70)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[7][8], 71)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                {this.renderSquare(array[8][0], 72)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[8][1], 73)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[8][2], 74)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[8][3], 75)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[8][4], 76)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[8][5], 77)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[8][6], 78)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[8][7], 79)}
                {this.renderSquare(array[8][8], 80)}
                </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      class Game extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <div className="game">
              <div className="game-board">
                <Board />
              </div>
              <div className="game-info">
                <div>{/* status */}</div>
                <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      // ========================================

      ReactDOM.render(
        <Game />,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
```

Comment: I try to create a boar who have 81 squares, these squares have inside an a input with a value and a id, when i creacte the inputs i want to this have a event onkeypress to when i put a number inside of the imputs that will call the function comprovar givin him tha id and the value of the imput, this function will put the imputs background on color red if it is not the correct number or will stay withe if it is correct. I have the problem on react code because i dont know how to creacte the squares and imputs with the event, value and imput and how to change their background color.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you are using wrong the onKeyPress event handler, it should receive a reference to function and not execute the function this way:

```
 function Square(props) {
    const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
       comprobar(props.value, props.id) 
    }
        return (
          <input className="square" type="text" onkeypress={handleKeyPress} />
        );
      }
```

also you don't need to pass onkeypress when using Square component:

```
renderSquare(a, i) {
            if (valoresVacios.indexOf(i)) {
              return <Square value={0} id={i} />;
            } else {
              return <Square value={a} id={i} disabled />;
            }
          }
```

Comment: That works and i undertanded that, thx, but now the problem is that when i generate the squares their value is null in all.

Comment: I have this warning too.  index.js:1446 Warning: Invalid event handler property `onkeypress`. Did you mean `onKeyPress`?
    in input (at src/index.js:137)
    in Square (at src/index.js:154)
    in div (at src/index.js:168)
    in div (at src/index.js:166)
    in Board (at src/index.js:277)
    in div (at src/index.js:276)
    in div (at src/index.js:275)
    in Game (at src/index.js:291)

Comment: I think the problem with you passing ```value={0}``` and not ```value={a}``` try to see if it is what you wanted to achieve here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l32wky2wjl

Comment: Thats a solution but if i do this, i have a compleate sudoku and when i want to put a number combrobar i dont know why not works. Thax

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an array inside state. this.

```html
const filledArray1 = new Array(81).fill("1");
const filledArray2 = new Array(81).fill("white");
    this.state = {
      cellValues: filledArray1 , 
      cellBackgroundColors:filledArray2
      }
      
      loadValues=()=>{
      
         const newValues= [ 1,"" , 5 , "" , 6 ,  .......   ] ;  // 81 
         this.setState( { cellValues : [...newValues ] })
      
      }
      
      componentDidMount(){
      
         loadValues(); 
      
      }


      loadValues=()=>{
      
         const newValues= [ 1,"" , 5 , "" , 6 ,  .......   ] ;  // 81 
         this.setState( { cellValues : [...newValues ] })
      
      }
      
      
      componentDidMount(){
      
         loadValues(); 
      
      
      }
```

since you will have placeholders to hold those values to their coordinates inside your cells. whenever you change your arrays new values will be shown in your cells.

[my youtube video on this subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYVY0R0jTR4&feature=youtu.be)